# play an audio with JW Player showing only the control bar

Tags: asp.net, audio, jwplayer

Im playing my audios with JW Player, but the problem is .. i dont want any video background. i only want to show the controlbar, it is showing when i HOVER it. I want to display only the controlbar and without hovering..I got many solutions from google, but the thing is i dont want to change the height of the player neither the height of the controlbar.There surely is a method that displays only the controlbar. no ??
Thanks alot ! 

This is my code:

```
jwplayer("container").setup({
                autostart: true,
                flashplayer: "player.swf",
                file: name,
                height: 270,
                width: 480
            });
```

I tried wmode:"none", but it displays the loading and shows me the controlbar on hover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just adjusting the height:

```
jwplayer("container").setup({
                autostart: true,
                flashplayer: "player.swf",
                file: name,
                height: 24,
                width: 480
            });
```

EDIT: this is shown at http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/15993/playing-an-audio-file